# Understanding State Monad

Tags: haskell

Looking at [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#state)'s definition of the `State Monad`:

```
instance Monad (State s) where  
    return x = State $ \s -> (x,s)  
    (State h) >>= f = State $ \s -> let (a, newState) = h s  
                                        (State g) = f a  
                                    in  g newState
```

I don't understand the types of `h s` and `g newState` in the lower right-hand side.

Can you please explain their types and what's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`State s a` is a naming of a function---the "state transformer function"

```
s -> (a, s)
```

In other words, it takes an input state `s` and modifies that state while also returning a result, `a`. This forms a really general framework of "pure state". If our state is an integer, we can write a function which updates that integer and returns the new value---this is like a unique number source.

```
upd :: Int -> (Int, Int)
upd s = let s' = s + 1 in (s', s')
```

Here, `a` and `s` end up being the same type.

---

Now this is all fine and good, except that we're in trouble if we'd like to get *two* fresh numbers. For that we must somehow run `upd` twice.

The final result is going to be another state transformer function, so we're looking for a "state transformer transformer". I'll call it compose:

```
compose :: (s -> (a, s))         -- the initial state transformer
        -> (a -> (s -> (b, s)))  -- a new state transformer, built using the "result"
                                 -- of the previous one
        -> (s -> (b, s))         -- the result state transformer
```

This is a little hairy looking, but honestly it's fairly easy to write this function. The types guide you to the answer:

```
compose f f' = \s -> let (a, s')  = f s
                         (b, s'') = f' a s'
                     in  (b, s'')
```

You'll notice that the `s`-typed variables, `[s, s', s'']` "flow downward" indicating that state moves from the first computation through the second leading to the result.

We can use `compose` to build a function which gets two unique numbers using `upd`

```
twoUnique :: Int -> ((Int, Int), Int)
twoUnique = compose upd (\a s -> let (a', s') = upd s in ((a, a'), s'))
```

---

These are the basics of `State`. The only difference is that we recognize there's a common pattern going on inside of the `compose` function and we extract it. That pattern looks like

```
(>>=) :: State s a     -> (a -> State s b   ) -> State s b
(>>=) :: (s -> (a, s)) -> (a -> (s -> (b, s)) -> (s -> (b, s))
```

It's implemented the same way, too. We just need to "wrap" and "unwrap" the `State` bit---that's the purpose of `State` and `runState`

```
State    :: (s -> (a, s)) -> State s a
runState :: State s a     -> (s -> (a, s))
```

Now we can take `compose` and compare it to `(>>=)`

```
compose f f'       =         \s -> let (a, s')  = f s
                                       (b, s'') =           f' a  s'
                                   in  (b, s'')

(>>=) (State f) f' = State $ \s -> let (a, s')  = f s
                                       (b, s'') = runState (f' a) s'
                                   in  (b, s'')
```

Comment: thanks - that answer helped me out. In `twoUnique = compose upd (\a s -> let (a', s') = upd s in ((a, a'), s'))`, you could've called `upd a` rather than `upd s`, right? I suppose it's arbitrary?

Comment: It happens to be the same, but that's just because, in this example, I kept unifying `a = s = Int`. In general, that wouldn't type check.

Answer (score 2):

The `State` Monad certainly is confusing the first time you see it. The first thing that's important to understand is its data declaration, which is

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }
```

so a `State` contains a function with the type `s -> (a,s)`. We can think of this as a function acting on some sort of generator and returning a tuple of a value and a new generator. This is how random numbers work in Haskell, for example: `s` is the generator while `a` is the result of the function that takes a generator as input and outputs a random number `a` (say, of type `Int`, but it could just as easily be any other type).

Now let's talk about the instance declaration. Recall the type of `(>>=)` is

```
Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

In particular, we note that `f` should have the type `a -> m b`. In this case, `m` is `State s`, so the type of `f` should be `a -> State s b`. So now we can break down the instance declaration

```
(State h) >>= f = State $ \s -> let (a, newState) = h s  
                                    (State g) = f a  
                                in  g newState
```

Since `f` has the type `a -> State s b`, the type of `State g` must be `State s b` (i.e. `g :: s -> (b,s)`), and since `h` has the type `s -> (a,s)`, we must have `newState :: s`. Thus the result of the bind expression is `g newState`, which is of type `(b, s)`.

For further reading, [here](http://brandon.si/code/the-state-monad-a-tutorial-for-the-confused/) is a great article that helped me to understand the `State` Monad when I first came across it.

Comment: Why is it necessary to call `State $ \s -> ...` in `>>=`'s definition? Your answer explaining the types helped (thanks), but I'm unclear what `\s -> ...` is doing.

Comment: Essentially, that's defining what `runState` is in the resulting `State`.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of the `State` monad at LYAH:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }
```

This means the argument to the `State` data constructor is a *function* which takes a state and produces an `a` and a new state. Thus `h` in the example above is a function, and `h s` computes `a` and `newState`.

From [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) we see the definition of `(>>=)` is

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

which means `f` is also a function from `a` to `State s b`. Thus it makes sense to give `f` the argument `a`, and the result is a `State`. Just like `h`, `g` is the argument to a state constructor which takes a state (in this case `newstate`) and return a pair `(a,newState2)`.

It might be more instructive to ask what `(>>=)` actually *does*: it lifts the function argument to a monad. A `State` is just a placeholder for a value depending on the current state, which is why the argument to the constructor depends on the state. Thus given a `State` "value", we first apply the state `\s -> let (a, newState) = h s` to get the corresponding value and a new state. Now we pass that value to the function (note that the types match up) and get a new state, i.e. a new function from a state to a value. Finally, we evaluate that state at `newState` to thread the state to the next part of the computation.